# Use the quotient rule of logs to expand $\log_3\frac{7x^2+21x}{7x(x-1)(x-2)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I am to expand $\log_3\frac{7x^2+21x}{7x(x-1)(x-2)}$ using the quotient rule of logs. I arrived at:

$$\log_3(7)+\log_3(4)+\log_3(x)-\log_3(x-1)-\log_3(x-2)$$

Whereas my textbook solution is:

$$\log_3(x+3)-\log_3(x-1)-\log_3(x-2)$$

It looks like I got it right for the denominator part but not the numerator. I don't see how to arrive at $\log_3(x+3)$ from $7x^2+21x$?

My train of thought was to divide $7x^2$ in the numerator by the $7x$ in the denominator leaving me with $7x+21x = 28x$ in the numerator and just $(x-1)(x-2)$ in the denominator.

With $28x$ in the numerator I expanded out to be $$\log_3(7)+\log_3(4)+\log_3(x).$$

Where did I go wrong, and how can I arrive at $$\log_3(x+3)-\log_3(x-1)-\log_3(x-2)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First isolate $7x$ from the numerator. You then have $\log_3\left[\frac{7x(x+3)}{7x(x-1)(x-2)}\right] = \log_3\left[\frac{(x+3)}{(x-1)(x-2)}\right] _{(x\ne0)} = \log_3(x+3)-\log_3(x-1)-\log_3(x-2)$

Answer (score 1):

"My train of thought was to divide 7$x^2$ in the numerator by the 7 in the denominator leaving me with 7+21=28 in the numerator and just (−1)(−2) in the denominator."

Once re-read your statement!!
when you divide 7$x^2$ with 7x you end up with x not 7x;

you will be left with (x+3) not (7x+21x) when you divide (7$x^2$ + 21x)/7x .

Comment: Also very helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can factor the numerator and denominator, both have a common factor $7x$, so you have
$$\frac{7x^2+21x}{7x(x-1)(x-2)}=\frac{x+3}{(x-1)(x-2)},$$ now you can use the $\log$ rules and get the answer that the book gives